# Styles.Render de popUp rompe pantalla base

Tags: javascript, css, diseño, style, server-side-rendering

Les quiero pedir ayuda con un problema que estoy teniendo.
Estoy cargando una grilla en un PopUp (el cual esta en una view como @Html.Partial) en la cual se puede seleccionar una fila y esto abre otro PopUp  para edición.

El problema que tengo que es:
Para que el PopUp se vea bien, al seleccionar una fila que cambie de color y todo lo que respecta a estilos, necesito de agregar
@Styles.Render("~/Content/web-css") en la pantalla Base.
Pero al agregarlo, me desarma toda la pantalla base. Si lo quito el popUp no levanta ningún estilo.

Que podria hacer?
tampoco pude llegar al archivo Content/web-css, lo busque como un archivo en la raiz y no lo encontré.
Se podra hacer algun codigo, solo tenga en cuenta el @Styles.Render("~/Content/web-css") si el pop up esta abierto ?

Tal vez algun codigo como .load que al cargar el view del popup recien ahi cargue el Render.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: si acierto en este acertijo, el problema lo tienes con css en asp.net, quieres agregar una parcial unas clases, en teoria vienen dadas del padre y no tienes que invocarlas, si lo que quieres es lo contrario tienes que invocarla en la partial

Comment: Hola Nicolas, desde ya gracias por tu colaboracion y si me indicas de que forma mejorar mi consulta bienvenido sea. :-)
Exactamente. Lo que necesito es que el Render se cargue solo en el PopUp pero lo agregue bajo la etiqueta script y no me lo reconoce. Es como que no existe en el padre entonces no hace nada.